# How to make a list out of all second elements of a tuple in haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

I have a list of tuples like
[(1,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C")]

Now I want to create a list with all the second elements of those tuples
so the list should be 
["A","B","C"]

can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by running `map snd [(1,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C")]`. The `map` function is defined to apply the function given as its second argument to each element of the list given as its third argument; the `snd` function gets the second element of a tuple.

Alternatively, if you prefer list comprehensions, you could do `[x | (_, x) <- [(1,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C")]]`; this takes each element of the list, matches it to the pattern `(_, x)` (which assigns the second element of each tuple to `x`), and then returns each `x`.